# combining records from two tables in mysql ordered by date

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am having two mysql tables. One table is for "received payments" and another for "payments made". Both tables have some of the fields common but some are different like received payments have a additional column of 'badDebt' and so on.
Both the tables have a date column.

Now i need to generate a complete transaction statement from these two tables datewise. So i planned for using UNION with ORDERBY. But it will not work because the number of columns needed to be same in this.

In my case columns differs. What should be done in this situation?

Comment: please post schema of your tables and desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dummy/placeholder columns.

e.g.

```
select col1, NULL as col2, col3 from Table1
union all
select col1, col2, Null as col3 from Table2
```

Use NULL or an appropriate dummy value for the missing columns.

The 'AS" statement is used to give the dummy column a name. Strictly speaking, I believe only the first `SELECT` in the `UNION` needs to define column names, but I prefer to be explicit.

Comment: i didn't understand the "as" part in both the select queries. What columns do they correspond to in each query?

Comment: also, is there a way i can get all the columns from both the tables by using *?

Comment: No, not if they have differing numbers/types of columns (as you have stated).

Answer (score -1):

Try to use UNION Syntax.

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name1
UNION
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name2
```

The UNION operator selects only distinct values by default. To allow duplicate values, use UNION ALL. Hope it can help you.

Comment: have you read the question properly? I have already mentioned that because the number of columns differ in both the tables. and in unions number of columns has to be the same. Please see the Mitch Wheat's answer.